# How structure in c can be assesed and input is given through pointer variable?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, malloc

I'm trying to implement struct with pointer.I got an an big problem that  i introduced a struct pointer variable and allocated memory using malloc
let the pointer variable be "ptr", then the ptr will contain address. then why we are using '&' in fornt of ptr variable. 
(scanf("%s %d", &(ptr+i)->subject, &(ptr+i)->marks);)

Lets take another example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, *ptr, sum = 0;

    printf("Enter number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    ptr = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if(ptr == NULL)                     
    {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Enter elements: ");
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", ptr + i);
        sum += *(ptr + i);
    }

    printf("Sum = %d", sum);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Here why we are not using '&' before ptr for getting ip??

clarify both the cases??

I have done without using '&' in scanf while using structure

```
struct course
{
   int marks;
   char subject[30];
};

int main()
{
   struct course *ptr;
   int i, noOfRecords;
   printf("Enter number of records: ");
   scanf("%d", &noOfRecords);

   ptr = (struct course*) malloc (noOfRecords * sizeof(struct course));

   for(i = 0; i < noOfRecords; ++i)
   {
       scanf("%s %d", &(ptr+i)->subject, &(ptr+i)->marks);
   }

   printf("Displaying Information:\n");

   for(i = 0; i < noOfRecords ; ++i)
       printf("%s\t%d\n", (ptr+i)->subject, (ptr+i)->marks);

   return 0;
}
```

if "&" is given running properly
if not it showing segementation fault

Answer (score 1):

`&(ptr+i)->marks` is equivalent to `&((ptr+i)->marks)`, which is equivalent to `&(ptr[i].marks)`.
That is, the `&` does not apply to the pointer `ptr`, it applies to a member of the struct `ptr[i]`.
And the `marks` member is an `int`, so you need to pass a pointer.

The `&` in front of `(ptr+i)->subject` (`ptr[i].subject`) should not be there, since that already gets converted to a `char*` when passed to the function.